# How can I pull a value out of a stream?

Tags: frp, bacon.js

Functional reactive programming implementations seem to have the observer as being passively dependent upon streams providing them with values.

Is it possible to request a new value from down stream?

For example, if I have a stream that serves co-ordinates of the apple in the game Snake, if the apple has been eaten then how can I ask for a new value?

The source stream doesn't know that a new apple is required.

[This](http://philipnilsson.github.io/badness/) has an interesting implementation that uses recursion.

```
function apple() {
  var applePos = randomPos()
  return 
     position
      .filter(p => p.equals(applePos))
      .take(1)
      .flatMapLatest(apple)
      .toProperty(applePos)
}
```

Is there a more straight forward way of doing this?

Perhaps I could have a stream that knows when a value has been taken and immediately generates a new one and holds it in a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

> The source stream doesn't know that a new apple is required.

I think that's the problem. In proper FRP, the `apple` function should have a parameter with a stream of `apple eaten` events, so that it can know when to produce a new apple.

Comment: Aha... yes the apple stream listens for the eaten event.